# want to find the id of a price table in wordpress, want to get the price table details in cart page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I want to get the price table details at cart page, mean to say when a user clink on purchase button then Package name, Price should be added in card page. After searching on google I found that I need to add a link on purchase button like [www.skgraphics.design/cart/?add-to-cart](http://www.skgraphics.design/cart/?add-to-cart) id=?. here is confusion I am unable to find the id of that price table.

**Please help me with this**